# Why the same image put in the "drawable-hdpi" directory shows different if I put it into the "drawable" directory

Tags: android

I have encountered a thing that I am not really able to understand.

In my application I use an image (64x64 px).

Now, ON THE SAME DEVICE (Samsung Galaxy ACE, Gingerbread):

- If i put the above mentioned image in the "drawable-hdpi" directory it shows on the screen in a certain size;
- If i put THE SAME IMAGE in the  "drawable" directory it shows in a **different size**, to be precise it shows **BIGGER**.

I really do not understand this!!

**It is the same image on the same device !!!**

Please is anybody able to explain to me this inexplicable behavior?

Thanks a lot to anybody so kind to clarify this to me.

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

See the screens. **The image in question is the background of each cell in the GridView**

**In the "drawable-hdpi" directory:**

[image]

**In the  "drawable" directory**

[image]

Comment: a screenshot would help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543233/android-are-images-of-the-same-size-rendered-differently-if-placed-in-different)

Comment: hdpi is a screen density qualifier. It has some implicit image scaling attached to have proportionally similar image sizes on different screens with different densities. The plain "drawable" folder is actually supposed to store XML-file drawables such as state lists or shape definitions. Maybe in case of image files it behaves the same as putting them into "drawable-nodpi" which does not apply any scaling at all. That's why your image appears bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android scales your image while keeping the aspect ratio. you can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and you can also put the file in drawable-nodpi as @Nobu said.